# I Want to iterate over some IP address and networks, to check if a IP belongs to a particular network

Tags: python-3.x, list

I Want to iterate over some IP address and networks, to check if an IP belongs to a particular network.

This is what I have written so far.

```
import netaddr, ipaddress

from netaddr import *

IP_found = []

IP_miss = []

dca = ['172.17.34.2', '172.17.33.1', '172.17.35.1', '172.17.36.2']

ip_net = [IPNetwork('172.17.34.0/27'), IPNetwork('172.17.35.0/27')]

for element in ip_net:
    temp = ipaddress.ip_network(element)
    for ip in dca:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in (temp):
            IP_found.append(ip)
            break
        else:
            IP_miss.append(ip)

print(len(IP_found))
print(len(IP_miss)) 

print(IP_found)
print(IP_miss)
```

This is my expected output.

```
IP_found -> ['172.17.34.2', '172.17.35.1']

IP_miss -> ['172.17.33.1', '172.17.36.2']
```

I got the below output:

```
['172.17.34.2', '172.17.35.1']

['172.17.34.2', '172.17.33.1']
```

Comment: I would try swapping the way you are doing your loops. Try iterating over the `dca` list first, it might make things easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import netaddr,ipaddress

from netaddr import *
IP_found = []
IP_miss = []
dca = ['172.17.34.2', '172.17.33.1', '172.17.35.1', '172.17.36.2']
ip_net = [IPNetwork('172.17.34.0/27'), IPNetwork('172.17.35.0/27')]

for ip in dca: # Loops through the ip
    if any(ip in ip_subnet for ip_subnet in ip_net): # Loops through subnet
        IP_found.append(ip) 
    else:
        IP_miss.append(ip)

print(len(IP_found))
print(len(IP_miss))
print(IP_found)
print(IP_miss)
```

Try this instead.